# How to define a collision between a bullet and a drawn sphere object

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I created a new project of type FPS, then I drew 10 spheres.
I am asking you about creation of such a custom event in my actor where I drew those spheres, so that I could call that custom event out of a blueprint with the bullet,
where I actually implement hit detection of the bullet with one of those spheres. Can I detect the hit with a sphere which is not an actor, and is just a drawn object?

Comment: You could create a sphere collision component (has a on overlap delegate) for each drawn sphere.

Answer (score 1):

sivak,

There's a few ways you can go about resolving this problem, I will describe them in detail below:

1. As George suggested in the comment above ,you can add a sphere collision for each one of these spheres. You will have to give the relative transform of these spheres which you can easily get from the spheres you have drawn, to differentiate between each of these sphere collisions you will have to promote each of them to a variable (or drag out the "Return Value" and set it to an object in the variables). You can then do an EventHit or OnEventBeginOverlap (whichever is more suitable for your purposes) from your bullet blueprint and you will be able to see which sphere your bullet is hitting. (Bear in mind, this will give you the "Sphere Collision" that you are hitting and not the static mesh / drawn sphere itself but there are ways in which you can get a reference to the original sphere using this)
   [image: Add Sphere Collision + Promoted to variable]
2. The second way to go about doing this, which is more suitable if you have a blueprint for the sphere actor and are making 10 copies of this in the level would be to do a SphereOverlapComponents. You will have to give the location of the drawn sphere and the radius as input. You can also set a component class filter allowing you to only consider collisions with the bullet. This will allow you to detect which Sphere you are colliding with. IMO this is an easier way to go about doing this but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so I will leave it up to you.
   [image: SphereOverlapComponents]

Which of these ways is better depends on your needs and what you intend on doing after you have detected the collision with the bullet.

I hope my answer was helpful to you, Please let me know if you have any more questions and I'll try my best to help you out :)